# Find N largest elements in a list with a minimum distance

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to extract from a list the N largest elements, but I want that for any two elements `x[i]` and `x[j]`, `abs(i-j) > min_distance`.

`scipy.signal.find_peaks(x, distance=min_distance)` offers this functionality. However I need to repeat this operation millions of times and I was trying to speed up a bit the operation.

I noticed that `find_peaks` does not accept a parameter `N` to indicate how many peaks you want to extract. It also doesn't allow to return the peaks from largest to smallest, requiring an additional call to `l.sort()` and `l = l[:N]`.

I tried to code a lazy sorter that only looks for the N largest elements without sorting the rest of the list.

Following the results obtained [here](https://ondergetekende.nl/lazy-sorting-in-python.html) I opted for `heapq`. This is my try:

```
import heapq

def new_find_peaks(x, N, min_distance=0):
    x = enumerate(x)

    x = [(-val,i) for (i,val) in x]
    heapq.heapify(x)

    val, pos = heapq.heappop(x)
    peaks = [(-val, pos,)]

    while len(peaks)<N:

        while True:
            val, pos = heapq.heappop(x)
            d = min([abs(pos - pos_i) for _,pos_i in peaks])
            if d >= min_distance:
                break

        peaks.append((-val, pos,))

    return map(list, zip(*peaks)) #Transpose peaks into 2 lists
```

This is, however, still 20 times slower than `find_peaks`, probably due to `find_peaks` CPython implementation. Also, I noticed that almost half of the time is spent on

```
x = [(-val,i) for (i,val) in x]
```

Do you have any better idea to speed up this operation?

---  minimal reproducible example ---

For example:

```
x = [-8.11, -7.33, -7.48, -5.77, -8.73, -8.73, -7.02, -7.02,
 -7.80, -10.92, -9.36, -9.83, -10.14, -10.77, -11.23, -9.20,
 -9.52, -9.67, -11.23, -9.98, -7.95, -9.83, -8.89, -7.33,
 -4.20, -4.05, -6.70, -7.02, -9.20, -9.21]

new_find_peaks(x, N=3, min_distance=5)

>> [[-4.05, -5.77, -7.8], [25, 3, 8]]
```

[image: x]

Note that `x[24]` is -4.2, but since `x[25]` is greater and `25-24 < min_distance`, this is discarded. Also note that `x[8]` is not a real peak, as `x[7]` is bigger, but this is discarded due to the distance with `x[3]`. This is an intended behavior.

Comment: is "minimum distance" always in one dimension?  If not what is your expected distance metric?

Comment: What you mean by “dimension”? It’s the distance in the list. I’m dealing with a list. It is one-dimensional

Comment: Well, `numpy` can accept any dimension of array, and the question gets much harder when you need to allow different metrics.

Comment: @SpghttCd sorry, it is in `scipy.signal`. I corrected the question.

Comment: @DanielF I’m aiming to have the function to work with plain `list`s.  The “metric” would be just the difference in the indexes

Comment: In this case, a peak is not exactly the same as a maximum... for instance what is the expected output on a monotonic decreasing array (there is only one peak, the first element, but the output could be the N first values spaced by min_distance)

Comment: @xdze2 I agree with you. But for my use case this definition is enough. I agree, however, that is a weak definition and that, in general, further checks (e.g. the second derivative) should be checked

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to have the top N pairs of elements of a list, sorted by the absolute difference of the indices of these pairs in the original list? Could you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: @SpghttCd I'm afraid you could have misunderstood the question. I added an example for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to speed up the calculations, I wrote a second algorithm that does not use heapq. This avoid the whole list to be reshaped in a heap queue.

The new algorithm looks like this

```
from heapq import nlargest

def find_peaks_fast(x, N, min_distance=0):

    peaks = []
    last_i = 0
    last_peak = x[0]

    for i, val in enumerate(x[1:], 1):

        if i - last_i == min_distance:
            # Store peak
            peaks.append(last_peak)

            # Store the new item and move on
            last_peak = val
            last_i = i

        elif val > last_peak:
            last_peak = val
            last_i = i

    return nlargest(N,peaks)
```

The algorithm scans through the list once and extract all the samples that are higher of both the N samples before and the N samples after. These are then stored in a list from where only the nlargest elements are extracted using heapq.nlargest

This, on its own, brings the execution time down to 3.7 ms. Quick, but still almost 4 times slower than scipy's find_peaks.

However, this can be changes using the package `numba`. This aims to "compile" the python code on-the-fly and to execute a compiled version to improve speed. And it improves it **a lot** !!

```
from numba import njit
from heapq import nlargest

from numba.errors import NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning)

@njit
def find_peaks_fast(x, N, min_distance=0):

    peaks = []
    last_i = 0
    last_peak = x[0]

    for i, val in enumerate(x[1:], 1):

        if i - last_i == min_distance:
            # Store peak
            peaks.append(last_peak)

            # Store the new item and move on
            last_peak = val
        last_i = i

    elif val > last_peak:
        last_peak = val
        last_i = i

return nlargest(N,peaks)
```

And testing it

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

from timeit import repeat
from numpy.random import randn

from numba import njit
from heapq import nlargest


def new_find_peaks2(x, N, min_distance=0):

    peaks = []
    last_i = 0
    last_peak = x[0]

    for i, val in enumerate(x[1:], 1):

        if i - last_i == min_distance:
            # Store peak
            peaks.append(last_peak)

            # Store the new item and move on
            last_peak = val
            last_i = i

        elif val > last_peak:
            last_peak = val
            last_i = i

    return nlargest(N,peaks)

@njit
def new_find_peaks2_jit(x, N, min_distance=0):

    peaks = []
    last_i = 0
    last_peak = x[0]

    for i, val in enumerate(x[1:], 1):

        if i - last_i == min_distance:
            # Store peak
            peaks.append(last_peak)

            # Store the new item and move on
            last_peak = val
            last_i = i

        elif val > last_peak:
            last_peak = val
            last_i = i

    return nlargest(N,peaks)


num = 500
rep = 10

N = 20
x = randn(20000)
sep = 10

code1 = '''
i_pks, _  = find_peaks(x, distance=sep)
pks = x[i_pks]
pks[::-1].sort()
pks = pks[:N]
'''

code2 = '''
_ = new_find_peaks2(x, N=N, min_distance=sep)
'''

code2_jit = '''
_ = new_find_peaks2_jit(x, N=N, min_distance=sep)
'''

i_pks, _  = find_peaks(x, distance=sep)
pks = x[i_pks]
pks[::-1].sort()
pks1 = pks[:N]
pks2 = new_find_peaks2(x, N=N, min_distance=sep)

print(pks1==pks2)

t = min(repeat(stmt=code1, globals=globals(), number=num, repeat=rep))/num
print(f'np.find_peaks:\t\t{t*1000} [ms]')

t = min(repeat(stmt=code2, globals=globals(), number=num, repeat=rep))/num
print(f'new_find_peaks2:\t{t*1000} [ms]')

t = min(repeat(stmt=code2_jit, globals=globals(), number=num, repeat=rep))/num
print(f'new_find_peaks2_jit:\t{t*1000} [ms]')
```

Leads to the result:

```
np.find_peaks:          1.1234994470141828 [ms]
new_find_peaks2:      3.565517600043677 [ms]
new_find_peaks2_jit:  0.10387242998695001 [ms]
```

That is a x10 speed up!

Conclusions:

- The algorithm could be sped up
- `numba.njit` proved to be an incredible wrapper, increasing the execution of the same function of almost 35 times!

Answer (score 1):

Improving your code in python could possibly give you some improvement, but as your code seems clean and the algorithm's idea sound, I don't think you will beat `find_peaks` with a python approach.

Hence I suggest you write your own library in a language that is closer to the metal, and write your own python wrapper if you need the result in python. For instance, you could use Swift. [Here](https://github.com/davecom/SwiftPriorityQueue) is an implementation of the heap queue in Swift and [here](https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/e111f0f64d0cdb8aca38) you find described a way to interface with python.

Connecting the dots is left as an exercise. ;)